# TensorFlowException: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /mnt/yarn/usercache

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to run "onto_electra_base_uncased" model on some data stored in hive table,
I ran count() on df before saving the data into hive table and got this exception.

Spark Shell launch configurations:

```
spark-shell spark.ui.port="4052"  --driver-memory 20g --executor-memory 45g  --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g spark.driver.extraClassPath="spark-nlp-assembly-2.7.5.jar,bdl-voltage.jar,vibesimplejava.jar,voltage-hadoop-5.0.0.jar,vsconfig.jar" spark.executor.extraClassPath="spark-nlp-assembly-2.7.5.jar,bdl-voltage.jar,vibesimplejava.jar,voltage-hadoop-5.0.0.jar,vsconfig.jar" --jars "spark-nlp-assembly-2.7.5.jar,bdl-voltage.jar,vibesimplejava.jar,voltage-hadoop-5.0.0.jar,vsconfig.jar"
```

Exception:

```
scala> nonNullPerson.count()
[Stage 9:>                                                        (0 + 8) / 200]21/08/23 10:07:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 309, ip-10-237-133-245.ec2.internal, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$dfAnnotate$1: (array<array<struct<annotatorType:string,begin:int,end:int,result:string,metadata:map<string,string>,embeddings:array<float>>>>) => array<struct<annotatorType:string,begin:int,end:int,result:string,metadata:map<string,string>,embeddings:array<float>>>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.serializefromobject_doConsume_1$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.mapelements_doConsume_1$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.deserializetoobject_doConsume_1$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.serializefromobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.mapelements_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage4.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:212)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ObjectHashAggregateExec.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:823)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndexInternal$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:823)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1629712606577_0001/container_1629712606577_0001_01_000003/tmp/7e8b5bbda7f3_ner3970436258867963111/variables
         [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1333)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
        at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.embeddings.BertEmbeddings.getModelIfNotSet(BertEmbeddings.scala:172)
        at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.embeddings.BertEmbeddings.annotate(BertEmbeddings.scala:223)
        at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.AnnotatorModel$$anonfun$dfAnnotate$1.apply(AnnotatorModel.scala:35)
        at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.AnnotatorModel$$anonfun$dfAnnotate$1.apply(AnnotatorModel.scala:34)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.tensorflow.TensorFlowException: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1629712606577_0001/container_1629712606577_0001_01_000003/tmp/7e8b5bbda7f3_ner3970436258867963111/variables
         [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]
        at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
        at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:326)
        at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:276)
        at com.johnsnowlabs.ml.tensorflow.TensorflowWrapper$.read(TensorflowWrapper.scala:325)
        at com.johnsnowlabs.ml.tensorflow.TensorflowWrapper.readObject(TensorflowWrapper.scala:248)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2295)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2404)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2186)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:502)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:460)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$8.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unBlockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:309)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:235)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1326)
        ... 43 more
```

I'm running this on EMR and its configuration is:

- Master(1) -> r5.2xlarge
- Core(2) -> r5.4xlarge
- Task(1) -> r5.4xlarge

Comment: The problem is related to the spark-nlp Bert graph. I see that you have included an assembly which corresponds to spark-nlp. That package includes the graph to execute the Bert encoder annotation. You have to check if the assembly is built ok (the TF graph is included), because the spark workers need to load the TF graph.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez can you provide more context, when I run same code in another env it works fine, fails only in one particular env, even works fine in spark local mode so I believe jars and dependency are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is use kryo serialization, the default spark-shell or spark-submit invocation is using java serialization, the Annotate class in spark-nlp is implemented to use Kryo Serialization hence same should be used for running any spark-nlp jobs